# Looking up Product Attributes and Customizable Options

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom-options, eav-attributes

I'm working with info`_buyRequest` data stored in Quotes. There are cases where super attributes as well as options are present in the `buyRequest`. These appear purely as DB id's, and I am trying to figure out the best way to access the associated metadata such as the text codes, store labels, etc.

Here is an example:

```
buyRequest:
 id                          =[354]
 product                     =[2131]
 selected configurable option=[1869]
 related product             =[]
 item                        =[354]
 super attributes:
   super attribute:          =[174]=>[159]
   super attribute:          =[172]=>[137]
   super attribute:          =[173]=>[157]
 options:
   option:                   =[38]=>[some entered value for custom option 38]
   option:                   =[36]=>[some entered value for custom option 36]
   option:                   =[37]=>[some entered value for custom option 37]
```

I need to look up the attributes with IDs **174,172,173** and find the associated strings for the values **159,137,157**.

Similarly, I need to look up the custom options with IDs **38,36,37** and find their names.

I am not sure what the best interfaces are to do this.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.